# Cannot change the parameters in the API endpoint key

Tags: api, xamarin.forms

I am a new Xamarin developer. I am trying to integrate a data API to my Xamarin forms cross-platform mobile app.
Following is the site that I get my URL endpoint: [navigate to the website](https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api-helper/url-generator.html)

Following is the API endpoint I get from the above site: `https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetterdate=latest&station=8518750&product=air_temperature&datum=MTL&time_zone=gmt&units=metric&format=json`

The API endpoint URL sends back data when based on the `weather station ID`parameter in the API endpoint. The problem is that it is hardcoded in the API endpoint itself. Therefore, I must change the whole API endpoint when I need to request data from another `weather station ID`.

I have no idea how to send the stationID as a variable in the same URL, like in following end point I got from **openweather API service**:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherlat{location.Latitude}&lon{location.Longitude}&appid=d6533ef259a2c612eb50836b198fc366&units=metric`

In the above API, I can send the `longitude` and `latitude` as parameters via the API key and get relevant information. But in my API key, I cannot see such a way to send a 'StationID' as a parameter.

Can somebody please help me to modify my following code to send the 'stationID' as a variable and get data dynamically based on the `station ID` please?

***Following is my code for getting API data send them to the .xaml front end.***

```
private async void GetTideInfo()
    {
        var url = $"https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetter?date=latest&station=8518750&product=air_temperature&datum=MTL&time_zone=gmt&units=metric&format=json";

        var result = await ApiCaller.Get(url);

        if (result.Successful)
        {

                    var tidalInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TidleRoot>(result.Response);

                    meanTideTxt.Text = tidalInfo.data[0].v + " m";
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Tidal data", "No tidal data found", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for everybody who volunteer to solve my problem.

Comment: You need to verify the alowed query parameters for https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod endpoint, this has nothing to do with xamarin or api, this is an GET request trou HTTP protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string, and it works as a function where you get inputs and outputs, you need to check the available inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just insert the StationID value into the url

```
var stationId = 8518750;
var url = $"https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetterdate=latest&station={stationId}&product=air_temperature&datum=MTL&time_zone=gmt&units=metric&format=json";
```